# Пропадает контент страницы при наличии якоря в ссылке

Tags: javascript, html

Есть одностраничник с внутренними страницами   http://ferrasil5.temp.swtest.ru/test/
Сделал, что при переходе из внутренних страниц на главную, она прокатывалась до выбранного в меню пункта с помощью #якорей, например http://ferrasil5.temp.swtest.ru/test/#products
При таких переходах, почему-то, пропадает Блоками контент (у большей части из него есть абсолютное позиционирование из-за скрипта parallax.js).  Место для контента остаётся, а самого Блока не видно и он куда то улетает

Comment: добавьте в ваш вопрос пример кода, разметки